# Getting properties of an object retrieved from DB by PDO fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_OBJ)

Tags: php, pdo

I do have an array of objects retrieved from DB with PDO fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ). When I var_dump first element of that array:
`var_dump($this->stockList[0]);`
I get:

```
object(stdClass)[5]
public 'userId' => string '3' (length=1)
public 'symbol' => string 'ibm' (length=3)
public 'date' => string '2019-01-03' (length=10)
public 'quantity' => string '5' (length=1)
public 'bought' => string '1' (length=1)
public 'observed' => string '0' (length=1)
public 'dividendRate' => string '6.28' (length=4)
public 'exDividendDate' => string '2018-11-08' (length=10)
public 'forwardDividend' => string '31.400000000000002' (length=18)
```

I would like to use reflection on this object to get all of it's properties:

```
$r = new ReflectionClass($this->stockList[0]);
$objProperties = $r->getProperties();
```

I get proper class:
`var_dump($r);` 
produces:`object(ReflectionClass)[16]
public 'name' => string 'stdClass' (length=8)`

but I can't get properties of that object:
`var_dump($objProperties);`
gives an empty array:
`array (size=0)
empty`
So, the question is how do I get a list of properties of that object?
My full code:

```
$sql = "query";
$this->stockList = $this->con->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

var_dump($this->stockList[0]);
$r = new ReflectionClass($this->stockList[0]);
$objProperties = $r->getProperties();
var_dump($r);
var_dump($objProperties);
```

Comment: Why do you need reflection to do this? `foreach($stockList as $stockItem) echo $stockItem->userId;` - All parameters are public already. If you want to get the parameter names, consider using `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and then use `array_keys()` which will hold `['id', 'symbol', etc..]`

Comment: or just `array_keys(get_object_vars($this->stockList[0]))` when relying on `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Didn't even thing to use `get_object_vars()`. Great suggestion.

Comment: @Jaquarh you may reference this in your more extensive answer.

Comment: get_object_vars() is great! Thanks. Out of curiosity - why reflection doesn't work? I used it on multiple occasions on my own classes and it worked fine.

@Jaquarh - I work with code that uses FETCH_OBJ as standard, so didn't want to change that.

Comment: @Bartek Because it is an StdClass, Reflection uses the class properties it knew before, StdClass has no 'set' properties, they can be infinite. If you built a new class, IE: class StockItem and placed these in, it would work. The equivalent for an stdclass is `get_object_vars ()`

Comment: @Jaquarh, great to know! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection with an StdClass will not work. The call to `ReflectionClass()`, parameter one uses the `::class` of the instance to determine its properties. Since StdClass has no properties at default and are given dynamically, Reflection can not find any properties since by default they do no exist.

You can see the above in a [demo](https://3v4l.org/d0Oaq). However, for even more simplicity, this would work fine:

```
var_dump(array_keys((array) new Foo('bar'))); # Based on above demo
```

However, do not panic. You do not need to use reflection to do this: `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` will give you a multidimensional array. You can use `array_keys()` to get the parameters. Then, later, if you prefer to use the result as an object, cast the array as an object.

```
# Fetch Query
$this->stockList = $this->con->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

# Get properties which will be, in this case, ['id', 'symbol', 'date', 'quantity', 'bought', 'observed', 'dividendRate', 'exDividentDate', 'forwardDivident']
$properties      = array_keys($this->stockList[0]);

# Revert all back to StdClass instances by casting the array to object
foreach($this->stockList as &$stockItem) {
    $stockItem = (object) $stockItem;
}
```

Alternativly, as suggested in the comments by [@Quasimodosclone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3741589/quasimodos-clone). You can use `get_object_vars()` which will return the array equivalent of the object. Then, like before, use `array_keys()` to get the properties.

```
$this->stockList = $this->con->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$properties      = array_keys(get_object_vars($this->stockList[0]));
```

After testing this out of curiosity, the object can be casted to an array to achieve more simplicity.

```
$this->stockList = $this->con->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$properties      = array_keys( (array) $this->stockList[0] );
```